# SuperMicro 1114S-WN10RT (1U, AMD EPYC 7763) «normal» fan speed?

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, fan

I cant find an information about "normal" fan speed for server.
Server: SuperMicro 1114S-WN10RT (1U) with 1x AMD EPYC 7763.

Now its 5% load:

```
user@server12:/home/user# ipmitool sdr list
CPU Temp         | 53 degrees C      | ok
Inlet Temp       | no reading        | ns
System Temp      | 26 degrees C      | ok
Peripheral Temp  | 38 degrees C      | ok
M2NVMeSSD Temp1  | no reading        | ns
M2NVMeSSD Temp2  | no reading        | ns
NIC Temp         | 25 degrees C      | ok
VRMCpu Temp      | 26 degrees C      | ok
VRMSoc Temp      | 42 degrees C      | ok
VRMABCD Temp     | 35 degrees C      | ok
VRMEFGH Temp     | 35 degrees C      | ok
DIMMABCD Temp    | 32 degrees C      | ok
DIMMEFGH Temp    | 30 degrees C      | ok
FAN1             | 7140 RPM          | ok
FAN2             | 7140 RPM          | ok
FAN3             | 7000 RPM          | ok
FAN4             | 7140 RPM          | ok
FAN5             | 7000 RPM          | ok
FAN6             | 7140 RPM          | ok
12V              | 11.98 Volts       | ok
5VCC             | 5.05 Volts        | ok
3.3VCC           | 3.36 Volts        | ok
VBAT             | 0x04              | ok
VDDCR            | 1.05 Volts        | ok
VMEMABCD         | 1.23 Volts        | ok
VMEMEFGH         | 1.24 Volts        | ok
VDD_5_DUAL       | 5.16 Volts        | ok
VDD_33_DUAL      | 3.33 Volts        | ok
SOCRUN           | 1.04 Volts        | ok
SOCDUAL          | 0.90 Volts        | ok
Chassis Intru    | 0x00              | ok
PS1 Status       | 0x01              | ok
PS2 Status       | 0x01              | ok
U2_SSDA Temp     | 30 degrees C      | ok
```

Parts List:

```
FAN FAN-0141L4  6   40x40x56 mm 20.5K RPM / 17.6K RPM Counter-rotating Fan
```

We try full load and fan speed was around «12000 RPM».

According to our feelings, when loading at 70%, the speed will be around «10000 - 11000 RPM».
I'm interest fan service life at this speed. Is it ok for this fan brand?

Comment: IME, Supermicro fan speed tends towards, "Ready for takeoff for a flight around the server room."

Comment: Fans and motors in general can fail for a variety of reasons other than operating speed. Usually they make loud noises before failing and given how inexpensive they are relative to what they are protecting just have spares on hand.

Answer (score 1):

According [Fan  speeds on Supermicro system via IPMI](https://serverfault.com/questions/662526/) it could be from between 4K to 8K RPM. The thread shows also how to work with sensor data. And than there is also documentation about [System Fans](https://www.supermicro.com/en/support/resources/thermal) in general.